# Cleaning up messy paragraph breaks in a dictionary in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a dictionary in MS Word format which I'd like to have cleaned from any paragraph breaks within dictionary entries, and keep only paragraph breaks that separate any two dictionary entries. This is how the layout of the dictionary looks now:

[First picture http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/6476/snapshotpr.jpg](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/6476/snapshotpr.jpg)

I'd need a macro or a regular expression that would first remove all the paragraph breaks, from the document, which would produce this layout:

[Second picture http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/5219/snapshot1i.jpg](http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/5219/snapshot1i.jpg)

and then in the next step would add paragraph breaks only before the dictionary entries, which means only before bold phrases followed by the phonetic transcription in square brackets, to get this layout:

[Third picture http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/2003/snapshot2qf.jpg](http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/2003/snapshot2qf.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?? If so, please add your code to the question. If not try to record macro in MS Word and do simply `find` >> `replace` operation which is the tip for what you need.

Comment: I'm not a programmer KazJaw, I can't create a code, or record a macro.I only know basic expressions used with Word's find and replace, and I know how to insert and run a macro in Word, that's all. I can remove paragraph breaks from my dictionary, but I don't know how then I can tell Word to add paragraph breaks only before those phrases in bold that are followed by whatever is within square brackets [ ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [this site](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm) to help me with the paragraph markers.

Again, I recorded a macro with something did manually with 4 find/replace (two steps were used to make sure that a word followed by a square bracket was matched). Here's the macro:

```
Sub Separator()
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^13"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchByte = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchFuzzy = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "\["
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchByte = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchFuzzy = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Font.Bold = True
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "[a-z\-]@ \["
    .Replacement.Text = "^p^&"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchByte = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchFuzzy = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Font.Bold = True
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find.Replacement.Font
    .Bold = False
    .Italic = False
End With
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "\["
    .Replacement.Text = "["
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchByte = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchFuzzy = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

End Sub

Let me know if there's anything to tweak and I'll try to change it :)

EDIT: Part added for hyphens.

Comment: Thank you for helping me Jerry. I've tried your macro and I've found two problems. First, it puts a paragraph mark not in front of the entry in bold but one word back, and what happens is that it glues the last word from the previous entry with the following entry word. Here's how it looks when I run it on the selection of words from my original post http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/4835/snapshot2yv.jpg . Another problem is that it splits hyphenated entries into half, inserting a paragraph mark after the hyphen in words, here's a pic http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/5219/snapshot1i.jpg

Comment: I deleted some lines from the code supposedly to make it shorter (somehow it was working fine when I tested it). I guess I'll reinsert them. Also, amended the code to match hyphens as well.

Comment: I've tried it Jerry, this one only removes all paragraph breaks, and doesn't make any other changes.